# data manipulation and deleting NA values with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, row

I have a different problem that I have not encountered yet.  When I try to make a completely reproducible example, I get errors, so I am posting what my data look like, and what I would like it to look like.  I am asking for suggestions on how to get the data into the shape I need to do some analyses.

Here is what the data look like:

[image: What the data look like]

[image: What I need the data to look like.]

If I am breaking some type of protocol, I apologize.  When I try to make a reproducible example, I get the following error:  "Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, 2, 3, value = 3) :
new columns would leave holes after existing columns"  This is the best I can do for some help.

I have tried binding rows, deleting rows with NAs, na.omit(), and several others.  I just need to get the data to where it is no longer 7 columns and 9 rows, but to 7 columns and 3 rows.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may loop `across` columns other than index, `order` based on the NA elements so that all non-NAs order at the top followed by NA and then use `filter` to remove the rows having all NAs with `if_any`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   mutate(across(-index, ~ .x[order(is.na(.x))])) %>%
   filter(if_any(-index, complete.cases))
```

NOTE: This will keep some NA rows in case there are difference in number of NAs per each columns

Comment: This did the trick.  When the system allows me to accept the answer, I will do so.  I appreciate the help.  Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

In base R you could do

```r
as.data.frame(lapply(df1, na.omit))
```

For example:

```r
df1 <- data.frame(a = c(1, 2, 3, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
                  b = c(NA, NA, NA, 4, 5, 6, NA, NA, NA),
                  c = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 7, 8, 9))

df1
#>    a  b  c
#> 1  1 NA NA
#> 2  2 NA NA
#> 3  3 NA NA
#> 4 NA  4 NA
#> 5 NA  5 NA
#> 6 NA  6 NA
#> 7 NA NA  7
#> 8 NA NA  8
#> 9 NA NA  9

as.data.frame(lapply(df1, na.omit))
#>   a b c
#> 1 1 4 7
#> 2 2 5 8
#> 3 3 6 9
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: The base R works as well.  Thank you.

Comment: I like this one as well, and have put them both into my code for safe keeping given the dplyr version above may need watching due to the unevenness of NA issue pointed out.